# Flatten a nested JSON structure in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an object stored in MongoDB which looks like:

```
{
_id: 123
name: "xyz"
    attrib: 
    {
       address: "123 xyz rd",
       phone: "123-456-7890"
    }
}
```

I want to flatted this structure, so that there is no `attrib` field, I just have `address` and `phone` field along with `name` and `_id`.

So far, this is what I've tried:

```
db.emp.aggregate(
    { 
    $project : {
            { addr : '$review.attrib.address' },
            { phn : '$review.votes.phone' },
        }
    }
);
```

Can anyone help me further?

Comment: Why not just flatten it on the client? There's no practical way to flatten the fields in MongoDB efficiently with all sizes of collections.

Comment: What do you mean by flattening on the client? How can I do that?

Comment: Use whatever programming language you plan on using and do your own client side projection of the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - $project nested document to root level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431243/mongodb-project-nested-document-to-root-level)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried it：

```
db.abc.insert({
  _id: 123,
  name: "xyz",
  attrib: {
     address: "123 xyz rd",
     phone: "123-456-7890"
  }
});
db.abc.aggregate(
{ 
  $project : {
    _id:1,
    name:1,
    addr : '$attrib.address',
    phn : '$attrib.phone' 
  }
}
);
```

More detail, you can see：`use $project to rename fields`  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/

Comment: I get this: "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size
(16MB)"

Comment: The aggregation framework currently returns the results as a single document as a result, the result is limited to the 16MB document size limit. The next release should include the ability to pipe the results into a collection eliminating this limitation. In the meantime, writing a MapReduce process is the way to go if you encounter the 16MB limit. If you only happen to need to retrieve a few documents at a time, you should start your pipe with a $match operator and/or use a $limit to possibly work within the 16MB limit.

Comment: I am struggling with writing a map/reduce function on MongoVUE. Any hint regarding that will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

**Since mongodb version 4.2**, you can use one update with aggregation pipeline of `$set` and `$unset`.

The **short and literal** option is:

```
db.collection.update({},
  [
    {$set: {
        address: "$attrib.address",
        phone: "$attrib.phone"
    }},
    {$unset: "attrib"}
  ],
  {multi: true}
)
```

[playground - literal](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vxUPkTQXG-N)

While the **generic option**, if you don't wan to specify all inner field, can be:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$attrib"]}}},
  {$unset: "attrib"}
],
{multi: true})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EA75gSdTIvx)

**For older versions** you can simply use `$rename`/`$set` and `$unset`:

(`$rename` is just a combination of `$set` and `$unset`)

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $rename: {
    "attrib.address": "address",
    "attrib.phone": "phone"
  }
}, {multi: true})
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y3GLBFt-pvA)

And later:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {attrib: ""}}, {multi: true})
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DCf87HLZqjr)

Answer (score 2):

If you are intending to change all the documents in the database, then neither the Aggregation Framework or Map/Reduce are they way to go. You instead write a script in your favourite language and loop over all the documents in the collection to modify them one by one.