# MongoDB - $project nested document to root level

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible **without writing all the sub-document's fields?**

Let's say I have the following document structure:

```
{
  field1: a,
  subdoc: {
          field2: b,
          field3: c
  }
}
```

I want to use `$project` in order to get the suboc at root level:

```
{
  field1: a,
  field2: b,
  field3: c              
}
```

This is just an example with 2 fields in the subdoc, my real document has many fields and more may be added or deleted in the future, so I want the `$project` to be more **dynamic and not to specify all the fields separately.**

Comment: You would need to use Map-Reduce first to get the keys for the subdocument then construct the `$project` document using the returned keys dynamically.

Comment: @chridam can you give an example for the schema above?

Comment: I've given the example in the answer below.

Answer (score 19):

For MongoDB 3.6 and newer, use aggregation framework with a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline that can be applied in conjunction with the **[`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)** operator as the `newRoot` expression.

This expression

```
{ "$mergeObjects": ["$subdoc", "$$ROOT"] }
```

will merge the top level fields in the document with the ones in the subdoc embedded fields so in the end your aggregate operation will be as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$replaceRoot": { 
        "newRoot": { 
            "$mergeObjects": [ "$subdoc", "$$ROOT" ] 
        } 
    } },
    { "$project": { "subdoc": 0 } }  
])
```

---

Otherwise you would need a mechanism to get all the dynamic keys that you need to assemble the dynamic **`$project`** document. This is possible through **[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/map-reduce/)**. The following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection with all the keys as the `_id` values:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "my_collection",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this.subdoc) { emit(key, null); }
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
    "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})
```

To get a list of all the dynamic keys, run distinct on the resulting collection:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["field2", "field3", ...]
```

Now given the list above, you can assemble your **`$project`** aggregation pipeline document by creating an object that will have its properties set within a loop. Normally your **`$project`** document will have this structure:

```
var project = {
    "$project": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": "$subdoc.field2",
        "field3": "$subdoc.field3"
    }
};
```

So using the above list of subdocument keys, you can dynamically construct the above using JavaScript's **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method:

```
var subdocKeys = db[mr.result].distinct("_id"),
    obj = subdocKeys.reduce(function (o, v){
      o[v] = "$subdoc." + v;
      return o;
    }, { "field1": 1 }),
    project = { "$project": obj };

db.collection.aggregate([project]);
```