# MongoDB how to change object to normal field

Tags: mongodb

I want to take off Object field `status_approve` and take out the value in it.
ex document ==>

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("....."),
      "status" : 8,
      "status_approve" : {
          "red" : 1,
          "green" : 0,
          "pink" : 4,
          "black" : 0
         },
      "status_duplicate" : 0
    }
```

change to

```
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("....."),
        "status" : 8,
        "red" : 1,
        "green" : 0,
        "pink" : 4,
        "black" : 0,
        "status_duplicate" : 0
    }
```

field in object `status_approve` will be moved outside

Comment: You can use _projection_ to convert object fields to document field. The `$project` or `$set` aggregation stages can also be used for that.

Comment: Where do you want to change this? In DB or In Query o/p.

Comment: See this post has similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431243/mongodb-project-nested-document-to-root-level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten a nested JSON structure in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935248/flatten-a-nested-json-structure-in-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks to everyone to help me ,Finally I use `$set`,`$unset` aggregation for my problem

Comment: If you used one or more of the solutions here, please up-vote it, so it will be easier to others to find it.